# Vue 3 extra params to emitted method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have two components "Parent", "Child"

Child (InputText):

```
<template>
     <input type="text" @input="$emit('updateData', $event.target.value)">
</template>
```

Parent:

```
<template>    
     <InputText @updateData="updateQuestion"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Parent",
  methods: {
    updateQuestion(val, param1, param2) {
      console.log(val) //child event.target.val
      console.log(param1) // param1 value passed in Parent template
      console.log(param2) // param2 value passed in Parent template
    }
  }
</script>
```

How can I add extra params to updateQuestion for example I need something like this:

```
<InputText @updateData="updateQuestion(<child params>, 'text1', 'text2)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an inline handler :

```html
<InputText @updateData="(childVal)=>updateQuestion(childVal, 'text1', 'text2')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

An event is available in component template as local `$event` value:

```js
<InputText @updateData="updateQuestion($event, 'text1', 'text2')"/>
```

Comment: Great, what if we passed more than one parameter from child?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Usually event value is designed the way it contains all data that is relevant to that event, e.g. `$emit('foo', { foo: $event.target.value, bar: ..., nativeEvent: $event })`